# rsyslog.conf rule for dmesglog doesn't work

Tags: linux, embedded, rsyslog, beagleboneblack

We have Beaglbone Black based custom board with Wifi chip
We have following entry in the `rsyslog.conf`

```
# Redirect all kernel messages including dmesg to /var/log/dmesglog
kern.*                         :omfile:$dmesg_log_rotation
```

dmesglog is flooded by wifi logs which starts with `mlan0` So I changed rule as follows,

```
# Redirect all kernel messages including dmesg to /var/log/dmesglog
kern.*, !contains, "mlan0" :omfile:$dmesg_log_rotation
```

However those logs still continues to flood the dmesglog.

Can someone suggest me what is wrong with that log ?
Any other suggestion for rule ? any pointers ?

**EDIT**:
After some digging I found that `rsyslogd -N1` can be used to check the `rsyslog.conf`. And that check pointed out error. I am trying to correct rule somehow.

**EDIT2**
I changed the rule as follows however now I don't see anything in the dmesglog

```
# Redirect all kernel messages including dmesg to /var/log/dmesglog
if ( 'kern.*' contains "mlan0" ) then{ action( type="omfile" file="*" ) } else { action( type="omfile" file="$dmesg_log_rotation" )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# Redirect all kernel messages including dmesg to /var/log/dmesglog
:msg, contains, "mlan0" ~
kern.*                         :omfile:$dmesg_log_rotation
```

According to [rsyslogd documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html) you should first discard the selected messages.

---

If you wish to put the filtered messages to a separate file, you can write something like:

```
# Redirect all "mlan0" to /var/log/mlan.log
:msg, contains, "mlan0" :omfile:/var/log/mlan.log
:msg, contains, "mlan0" ~
# Redirect all kernel messages including dmesg to /var/log/dmesglog
kern.*                         :omfile:$dmesg_log_rotation
```

Unfortunately, rsyslog doesn't support filtering exactly by the kernel module name, but you can try different properties (*msg* is only one of them), and you can specify the filter rule more accurately using rules "*startswith*", "*isequal*" or "*regex*". Full list of properties and rules is [**here**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/rsyslog.conf.5.html) (look below "*Available Properties*".
So you should try, for example:

```
:programname, startswith, "mlan" :omfile:/var/log/mlan.log
```

Or:

```
:syslogtag, regex, "^mlan[0-9]" :omfile:/var/log/mlan.log
```

I don't know If any property would contain the kernel mode. Anyway you can always filter by *msg* with *regex*.

```
:msg, regex, "^write-regex-matching-your-module-log-output" :omfile:/var/log/mlan.log
```

Comment: Just tempted to ask, can we redirect logs from particular kernel module to different file ?

Comment: You can redirect filtered messages to a different file. I added my answer with more examples. Hope it will help.